# How to Include excel file in ClickOnce publish (Visual Studio 2013)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to add Excel files in order to be published through ClickOnce . I've added the files in the project and its properties already marked as build content and copy always. However it is not being published through ClickOnce .

Could help me with this issue?

I thank the support .

Answer (score 0):

Here is the MSDN page for it

[How to: Specify Which Files Are Published by ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kzy0fky2.aspx)

EDIT: I apologize. I did not see where you had tried this. My bad. I'll run a quick test and see if I can recreate the problem.

Go to `Project > Properties` and then select the `Publish` tab at the bottom. From there select `Application Files`. You should see your file. Make sure that the options for the file are `Include (Auto)`, `(Required)`, and `Include`. That is what got my file to be added.